# Loading QGIS Coverage?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am using QGIS 2.8.2 and everytime I try to load in a coverage type Shapefile, like forest density or population density it all comes up as the same color, but has the sections marked for the density/coverage. I have attached a picture of my project when the Shapefile is loaded.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the layer style from single symbol to categorized or graduated.

See this tutorial for further details:

http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-styling-vector-data-in-qgis.html

Comment: Thank you! I am still learning to use QGIS and that had me stumped when I tried to load in shapefiles for those! Thanks again!!!!!!